# Object to Array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm using [this](http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/api/0.3/) library to read/write CSV files:

```
$csv = new SimpleExcel('CSV');
$csv->parser->loadFile('test.csv');
$csv->convertTo('JSON');
```

output is an object:

```
SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel Object
(
    [parser] => SimpleExcel\Parser\CSVParser Object
        (
            [delimiter:protected] => ,
            [file_extension:protected] => csv
            [table_arr:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Title
                            [1] => COST PRICE
                            [2] => REGULAR POST
                            [3] => REGISTERED POST
                            [4] => EXPRESS POST
                         )
                    ...
```

... but I can't convert it to an array with `json_decode` (`expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`) nor can I iterate over the `table_arr` because its a protected array.

Comment: @kingkero This is `SimpleExcel`, not `SimpleXML`.

Comment: http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/ shows examples of how to convert to JSON.

Comment: `$csv->convertTo('JSON');` ? I'm already doing that, which gives me the object.

Comment: The output you provided is from `var_dump($csv)` right?

Comment: right, print_r though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapped the library for this:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));
```